# Are Keras and PyTorch neural network models 100% compatible with each other?

Tags: keras, pytorch, neural-network

Can I train a neural network model using PyTorch and then use it in Keras, and vice versa?

Are PyTorch and Keras Neural Network models 100% compatible with each other?

Comment: The APIs are completely different. However, there exists ONNX, which is a standard ML model representation. In theory, you can switch between the two frameworks while training/deploying a model. In reality, the standard currently only "converts" a sub-set of the NN layers available on each framework. See: https://medium.com/mlearning-ai/switching-between-tensorflow-and-pytorch-with-onnx-86f0b1b4cff9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Short answer is `Not` **Pytorch by facebook** and **Keras by google** are *two different* frameworks for deep learning.

PyTorch and is known for its dynamic computation graph, while Keras is a neural networks API that runs on top of multiple deep learning frameworks such as TensorFlow

But it is always nice to build all your deep learning models using both (for learning purpose) and eventually you will choose your own framework.

Good Luck